# How to insert [return] in a Calendar (on iPhone) event

Tags: ios, keyboard, calendar

I am usually inserting return character within event I enter in Calendar on OS X.

Most notably to separate key informations, for example hour of a meeting start, and the title of the meeting (when time is required to prepare it
and to arrive to the location of the meeting):

```
    09:00
    Pr Wilson
```

I would like to make the same easy use of return on my iPhone.
The software keyboard has a <kbd>return</kbd> key, but I feel a deep deception every time I use it. When I type <kbd>return</kbd> key, the
software keyboard just exits.

How may I fluently insert returns in Calendar event?

For example, how may I insert a return where the cursor is within this event definition window?

[image: Calendar + return]

Comment: Apple wants you instead to enter the location in different fields (i.e. not include the time in the Event field, just put it in the start time field) and thus does not let you insert a newline.

Comment: 1. This is not the case on OS X. I include returns in all my event titles. •• return ••
2. Time was just an example. I regularly use return to present informations which have to be clearly separated and not stucked in piles.

Comment: Try pressing Shift then the return key on your iPhone ([source](https://jonathansblog.co.uk/how-to-enter-a-carriage-return-on-an-iphone-new-line))

Comment: I suggest you to try it.

Comment: Yeah, doesn't work. I'll keep trying. Have you tried other calendar apps?